# It is my logic or the syntax that i write is wrong ? (if else syntax)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a data from one worksheet to another worksheet using looping (`for`) and a condition (`if elseif else`). The conditions:

- If column E10 in wsCopy = empty then the code will loop...
- with the condition: If column B10 in wsCopy = Value in column Gs in wsDestI
- Then copy the value from column Gs wsDestI to column M wsDest
- Else if the value in column B10 wsCopy = empty
- Then do the condition.
- Else the code will copy from wsCopy to wsDest

But the code in the Else clause triggers an error:

> Run-time error '1004'

I tried to activate the worksheet but I'm still stuck. Can anyone explain why my source code is not working? Is it my logic or is the syntax incorrect?

```
 For i = 1 To lCopyLastRow
    If IsEmpty(wsCopy.Range("E" & 9 + i).Value) = True Then
        For s = 4 To b
            If (wsCopy.Range("B" & 9 + i).Value = wsDestI.Range("G" & s).Value) Then
                wsDestI.Range("C" & s).copy wsDest.Range("M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                wsDestI.Range("G" & s).copy wsDest.Range("S").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                wsDestI.Range("M" & s).copy wsDest.Range("P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next s
    ElseIf IsEmpty(wsCopy.Range("B" & 9 + i).Value) = True Then
            wsCopy.Range("E" & i + 9).copy wsDest.Range("M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsCopy.Range("K" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            wsDest.Range("S").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "0"
    Else:
    wsCopy.Activate
    wsDest.Activate
    'this below line is error and I don't know why its error
    wsCopy.Range("E" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("M").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    wsCopy.Range("B" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("S").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    wsCopy.Range("K" & 9 + i).copy wsDest.Range("P").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: If it was the syntax, there would be a *compile-time* error. Runtime error 1004 means your syntax is correct (code was compiled, and runs), but some Excel method is given a parameter value that Excel doesn't know what to do with, and throws error 1004.

Comment: Noted @MathieuGuindon thank you so much for sharing. I got a new problem though the nested for cannot copied the data, do you know why that's happen?

Comment: Is it throwing another error? Feel free to ask a new question specifically about it, since it appears to be a different problem.

Comment: its not throwing another error but the data won't be copied, ok then thank you so much! @MathieuGuindon

Comment: No problem - make sure you put up a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll actually get this error on every line with `wsDest.Range` because you aren't defining a row number for `.End(xlUp)` to start at, hence the error `1004`.

If you're trying to find the last row in the specified column, try adding `& Rows.Count` to the range you're trying to specify.

```
wsDest.Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: oh yes you are right! thank you so much @tate I get a new problem now, is my nested for is correct ? bsc the data is not copied